# Why we convert gray levels into double before using numeric operations on image in matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, double

Why we convert gray levels into double before using numeric operations on image in matlab?
Is it necessary to do so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because integer types like `uint8` have [saturated arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturation_arithmetic) in MATLAB, plus floating-point types have more precision when doing certain operations.

Also it is safer to upcast say a `uint8` to `double` than it is to downcast in the other direction.

---

Just to give an example, say you wanted to change the dynamic range of an image by raising it to a power of 2:

```
img = imread('peppers.png');
subplot(121), imshow(im2double(img).^2), title('double')
subplot(122), imshow(img.^2), title('uint8')
```

[image]

You can see how the `uint8` image got saturated with most values at 255.

Even more, using fraction exponents will throw an error for integer types:

```
>> img.^(1.1);
Error using  .^ 
Integers can only be raised to positive integral powers.
```

Comment: So it means that since in uint8 the range is [0, 255] so while doing arithmetic operations its range may overflow while in double the range is enough for doing arithmetic operations?